# Strange behaviour Select and $stateParams

Tags: javascript, angularjs, select, angular-ui

So I have a simple angular-ui route with some params, I'd like to change this params and so the route by selecting a select field.

Problem:
*The route works fine it changes to the right param but the select doesn't change to the option selected.*

Here is a working **[Plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/sB2xIHBMDxJErbE5587u?p=preview)**, if you click on Search link and then you change the select field, you will notice, the scope changes but not the selected option.

Controller:

```
.controller('SearchCtrl', ['$scope', '$state', '$stateParams', function ($scope, $state, $stateParams) { 
  $scope.data = {
      pageSizes: [12, 24, 48],
      pageSize: $stateParams.size,
      goSearch: {}
    };

  $scope.data.goSearch = function () {
    $state.go('search', {size: $scope.data.pageSize});
  }

}]);
```

Select:

```
<select name="pageSizes" id="pageSizes" ng-model="data.pageSize" ng-change="data.goSearch()" class="form-control">
     <option ng-repeat="label in data.pageSizes" value="{{label}}">{{label}}</option>
</select>
```

Please look at the [Plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/sB2xIHBMDxJErbE5587u?p=preview) for the rest of the code.

Comment: Oh well... I switched to AngularJS 1.4.10 and it works. Damn.

Answer (score 0):

I need to change `value` to `ng-value` or upgrade to AngularJs 1.4.6 which solved this issue https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/12005